# Add spacing between rows in Vuetify v-data-table

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change border-spacing iin the v-data-table to:

```
border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
```

I tried setting it with css:

```
v-data-table > div > table {
  border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

or

```
.v-data-table table {
  border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

But both of those did not work.
Any idea how can i change space between rows in v-data-table?

Comment: It will not work if you do it in the ```<style scoped></style>```

Comment: it works fine [here](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/bGdrXwE)

Comment: adding `border-spacing` it works on vuetify table

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist oh, so it is not possible without scoped? I need to contain the rest of the css in that component inside it so I need to use scoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the deep css selector `>>>` to do CSS injections into other components.

For example,

```
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ }
```

will be compiled down to

```
.a[data-v-f3f3eg9] .b { /* ... */ }
```

So you probably want to do something like

```
v-data-table >>> div > table {
  border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below selector

```
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table {
    border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).